# Meaning of "CC_DLL" in this line"class CC_DLL CCSize" in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-x

What is the specification of **CC_DLL** in this line"**class CC_DLL CCSize**" in Cocos2d-x.
Every Class in cocos2d-x Define like that --> class ..... classname
It create confusion for me. Plz help me out.

Thanks,

Comment: If you are using an IDE, you can probably either hover over the symbol to see what it is or click on it to get to its definition (providing it is not built-in). If you are not using an IDE, then you should be able to trace it through the include stack (manually) until you finally find the header it comes from. Do so, you will learn about your framework this way :) (and when you finally find a built-in if you cannot find its meaning by yourself, then it will be time to ask about it)

Comment: As a hunch: CoCos Dynamic Linked Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a preprocessor definition telling the module to either export or import the class.

Something like:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_COCOS
#define CC_DLL _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CC_DLL _declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

When linking against the library, `BUILDING_COCOS` is not defined, so `CC_DLL` will mean `_declspec(dllimport)`, which tells the compiler that the class is exported in a binary.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `CC_DLL` to be defined something like this (using MSVC intrinsics syntax):

```
#ifdef CC_IS_IMPLEMENTATION /* or CC_IS_DLL_COMPILATION or something like that */
#define CC_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CC_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

This is done to have a single definition that either exports or imports the class to/from a dll, based on whether the API is used by a user or by the implementation itself. The implementation (`.cpp` file) would then look something like this:

```
// .cpp file
#define CC_IS_IMPLEMENTATION
// CC_DLL is now defined to __declspec(dllexport)
#include "myapi_stuff.h"

// implement it...
```

And if a library / dll user uses that API (class), it is defined as `__declspec(dllimport)` to import the implementation from a dll.

Comment: You sure it's not _declspec(dllexport)?

Comment: @Luchian: I don't know what you mean. ♫ 0:)

Comment: Also, you sure the CC_IS_IMPLEMENTATION define is in the cpp file. What if the header is included by a cpp file in the same module? Are you sure the definition is file-scoped and not module-scoped?

Comment: @Luchian: It might aswell be module scoped / a project-wide preprocessor define (`/DCC_IS_DLL_COMPILATION` in my example), both would work.

Comment: @Luchian: Sure about what? The preprocessor define? Why wouldn't that work? A project I worked on did that just fine, unless I misremember something.

Comment: You'd be trying to import a symbol defined in the same module. VS issues a warning. I don't think that's correct. Or the proper way to do it. The proper way of doing it is a module-scoped preprocessor definition. Not the same thing.

Comment: @Luchian: Wouldn't it be bad to compile library and non-library stuff in the same module / project anyways?

Comment: @Luchian: Then I don't know what you mean, sorry.

Comment: You'd have to define CC_IS_IMPLEMENTATION in all implementation files, regardless of you actually export anything from them.